# Git Grep color options explained and/or compared

Tags: git, colors, config, git-config, git-grep

I'm trying to custom color my Git.

After reading through the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config), I've found my options I wanted to set.

Everything was working fine except the Grep.
I've realised, I haven't really used it in the past.

I wanted to set colors for it with the same palette, but I could not test some of them...

I have no idea what `matchContext` and `match` refer to and how they're different than `matchSelected` and `selected`.

`matchSelected` sets a color for the actual text I searched for, while as `selected` referred to the line-level(?) *context* of that match.

So, what is `match` doing? What does `matchContext` set? And where the hell is a good, detailed description for these?

Anyone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what the linked documentation says, trimmed a bit to make it all work out better:

> `context`
>
> non-matching text in context lines (when using `-A`, `-B`, or `-C`)
>
> `matchContext`
>
> matching text in context lines
>
> `matchSelected`
>
> matching text in selected lines
>
> `selected`
>
> non-matching text in selected lines

(I've left out `match`; we'll put that back in a moment).  Let's say we run `git grep findme`, just so we have a search word.

The three technical terms, such as they are, here are:

- *matching text*: This should be pretty obvious.  We're searching for the literal string `findme` so this is each occurrence of that string.  Color-coding the match is not as necessary for these kinds of fixed strings as it is for patterns: if we were searching for a pattern, it might be particularly useful to see just what the pattern matched.
- *context lines*: The clue here is the mention of the three flags.  You can get "before" context (`-B`), "after" context (`-A`), or both (`-C`), which basically means that if you are searching for `findme` and Git finds that, it will print out not just the line with the word `findme` in it, but also some lines before and after that line.

  Note that these before-and/or-after lines might *not* have `findme` in them—but then again, they might!
- *selected lines*: Git kind of hides what this means, but building on the above, it's fairly guess-able: we were searching for the word `findme` and it occurred in some line(s).  So those lines are *selected*, which distinguishes them from any context lines that did not have `findme` in them; those lines are not selected.  (But see below!)

Here's an example, in searching for the word `or`.  Git will color `or` in red, and otherwise do no coloring, by default, so I ran:

```
git -c color.grep.selected=green grep -C 2 -n or
```

which adds line numbers as well as using `selected=green`.  Unfortunately I can't get StackOverflow to color code this for me, so instead I'll use **bold** where Git uses green, and *italics* where it uses red:

`pfod.py-11-`                                                         
`pfod.py-12-This is basically a hybrid of a class and an OrderedDict,`
`pfod.py:13:or, sort of a data-only class.  When an instance of the`  
`pfod.py-14-class is created, all its fields are set to None if not`  
`pfod.py-15-initialized.`

Here we had two non-selected lines on either side, not in any color at all; and one selected line in the middle, with two occurrences of `or` within the one selected line.

In some cases the lines that *would* just be context, actually have a match:

`pfod.py-47-                self[field] = None`                                 
`pfod.py-48-        if len(kwargs):`                                            
`pfod.py:49:            raise TypeError('unexpected kwargs %s' % kwargs.keys())`
`pfod.py-50-        if len(args):`                                              
`pfod.py:51:            raise TypeError('unconsumed args %r' % tuple(args))`    
`pfod.py-52-`                                                                   
`pfod.py-53-    def __getattr__(self, attr):`

Here we had two non-selected lines at the outer edges, then two selected lines with a non-selected line in between.  This implies context lines can also be selected lines!  They can have both *non-matching* text and *matching* text.  There's something particularly weird about this, because if a context line has a match, it becomes a selected line—so why is there a `matchContext` at all?  If a context line has a match, it changes into a selected line.

Normally, setting `color.grep.matchContext` never has any effect, because if there *is* a match within what would have been a context line, it changes into a selected line and `color.grep.matchContext` no longer applies.  But when using `-v` everything gets swapped around.  This is where [the documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-grep) defines (albeit not very well) the term *selected*:

> `-v`, `--invert-match`
>
> Select non-matching lines.

That is, grep's `-v` option *inverts* the line selection.  Normally, finding a match means the line is selected, so you get `selected` (default = none, but I set `green` above) and `matchSelected` (default = "bold red") colors.  But with `-v`, every line that has a match is *de*-selected, and only *non*-matching lines are selected.  So now what *were* context lines are selected, and matching lines are de-selected.  So now for matching lines we get no color again, except for the match itself, where we get any `matchContext` color we set (default again "bold red").  (Of course, lines with the match only come out if you turn on context, since grep only outputs non-selected lines as context lines.  You can also set `color.grep.context` to get those `-v` context-ized lines colorized.)

Finally:

> `match`
>
> matching text (same as setting `matchContext` and `matchSelected`)

This is just shorthand to set both.  When `matchContext` is useless (non-`-v`), it effectively works out as an alias for `matchSelected`.  When `matchSelected` is useless (`-v`), it effectively works out as an alias for `matchContext`.  Git uses it internally to set the "bold red" default.

Comment: Hey! Your answer is awesome! I realised that I skipped some parts of the documentation, however, I wanted to put together a test and... well... I still don't get it all.
Somehow the whole thing bugged me. I could not exactly reproduce what I wanted. I could not "go back" to when I decided to open this question.
And finally, after sitting on it for at least 3 hours, I realised:
The order is key! I get different results just by changing the order of `match`, `matchContext`, `matchSelected` and `selected` in the _.gitconfig_ file!

Comment: So awesome! Why can't I give you more upvotes? And the trick with using `-c` option for one-time changes to configuration... priceless! Thank you, thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

> I wanted to set colors for it with the same palette, but I could not test some of them.

Check if you still have to compare/test those colors with Git 2.35 (Q1 2022, 5 years later):

The color palette used by "[`git grep`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/c0450ca09864baae1cd80b746500aaef2eeda956/Documentation/git-grep.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-grep))</sup> has been updated to **match that of GNU grep**.

See [commit b83f99c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b83f99c3990cc9080ec8f5459555069d47e4cdfb) (05 Jan 2022) by [Lénaïc Huard (`L3n41c`)](https://github.com/L3n41c).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit c0450ca](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c0450ca09864baae1cd80b746500aaef2eeda956), 10 Jan 2022)</sup>

> ### [`grep`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b83f99c3990cc9080ec8f5459555069d47e4cdfb): align default colors with GNU grep ones
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Lénaïc Huard</sup>

> [`git-grep`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b83f99c3990cc9080ec8f5459555069d47e4cdfb/Documentation/git-grep.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-grep))</sup> shares a lot of options with the standard grep tool.
> Like GNU grep, it has coloring options to highlight the matching text.
> And like it, it has options to customize the various colored parts.
>
> This patch updates the default `git-grep` colors to make them match the [GNU grep default ones](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/grep.1.html#ENVIRONMENT).
>
> It was possible to get the same result by setting the various `color.grep.<slot>` options, but this patch makes [`git grep --color`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b83f99c3990cc9080ec8f5459555069d47e4cdfb/Documentation/git-grep.txt#L192)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-grep#Documentation/git-grep.txt---colorltwhengt))</sup> share the same color scheme as `grep --color` by default without any user configuration.