# What is git reflog identity?

Tags: git

In `git`, I see that when using custom formatting for `git log`, there are "reflog identity" values possible. What is a reflog identity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These refer to *reflog entries*.  A *reflog* is simply a record of updates to a *reference*, and a *reference* itself is simply a generalization of branch and tag names and special names like `HEAD`.

Reflogs are normally enabled on client repositories (like yours) and normally disabled on server repositories.  This is, naturally enough, configurable.  The front end command people mostly use for looking at their reflogs is `git reflog`.  You can run that now if you like, but doing so won't help explain `%ge` and so on.  So we'll do something different:  Run `git log -g`.

Running `git reflog` basically runs `git log --oneline -g`.  By running `git log -g` yourself, you can leave out the `--oneline`, and hence see more than one line for each reflog entry.

The output will resemble the following, with names and email addresses changed:

```
commit 08b876daae9944d1a6fba271cfcd9629c13dfd69
Reflog: HEAD@{0} (A U Thor <thor@example.com>)
Reflog message: commit: initial torturetest code
Author: A U Thor <thor@example.com>
Date:   Sun Aug 7 01:59:31 2016 -0700

    initial torturetest code

commit 8bb118938b5c6a2978f13e74525b594a48226571
Reflog: HEAD@{1} (A U Thor <thor@example.com>)
Reflog message: checkout: moving from master to torturetest
Author: Someone Else <else@example.com>
Date:   Sat Jul 16 02:00:46 2016 +0200

    Allow backend ...
```

The most recent commit is one I made last night (well, this morning).  This is `HEAD@{0}`.  It represents some commit (whose true name is the big ugly SHA-1 hash starting with `08b87...`).  The commit itself has an author (me, though I changed the name here for display purposes), date, commit message, and so on—but the reflog entry, `HEAD@{0}`, *also* has an author (me again), date, and message.

In this case, the *commit*'s author and the *reflog* author are *the same*.  Even the reflog message is basically the same as the commit subject (the `Reflog message:` line just as the word `commit:` inserted).  So that's not much help—but take a look at the very next example, commit `8bb11...`.

This reflog entry has *me* as the *reflog author*, and someone else as the *commit author*.<sup>1</sup>  Moreover, the reflog *message*, `checkout: moving from master to torturetest`, is completely unrelated to the commit's subject line, which begins with `Allow backend`.

If you compare this to the short output from `git log -g --oneline` or `git reflog`—both of these examine the reflog for `HEAD`—you'll see only the *reflog message*, along with the commit ID and the reflog selector.

One other thing is worth noting here.  In regular `git log` output, each commit normally<sup>2</sup> appears only once.  In `git log -g` output, however, a commit can appear repeatedly, because Git is looking at the hash IDs stored in the reflog itself.  If you switch back and forth between branches that point to the same commit, or use `git reset` to change a branch to point back to a commit it pointed-to earlier, or run `git rebase`, or do any number of similar things, you can easily get a reference—this applies to both `HEAD` *and* branch names—that points to the same commit in multiple different reflog entries.

In my case, for instance, I apparently vacillated a bit on the name `torturetest` or something:

```
08b876d HEAD@{0}: commit: initial torturetest code
8bb1189 HEAD@{1}: checkout: moving from master to torturetest
8bb1189 HEAD@{2}: checkout: moving from torturetest to master
```

(I'm not really sure what this was about—perhaps just running too many Git commands without remembering which repository I was in. :-) )

Returning directly to your question:

> What is a reflog identity?

These are the names and email addresses stored in each reflog entry.  In the case of a private Git repository, on your own client, these are likely to all be the same all the time.  But since you can run `git config --global user.name "New User Name"` and `git config --global user.email new@address` any time to change them,<sup>3</sup> they could vary.

---

<sup>1</sup>That someone else is also the committer, if you get to wondering.  The commit's author and committer, and their corresponding dates and email addresses, are stored in the commit itself.  The reflog author, date, and email address are stored in the reflog entry.  It's actually a plain text file today, so you can just look at `.git/logs/HEAD` and `.git/logs/refs/heads/master` to see the raw reflog data.  The format is not particularly well documented, but is pretty obvious: it has the old and new values for the reference; the reflog's author, email, and date-stamp information; and the reflog message.

<sup>2</sup>The exception here, beside the one for reflogs themselves of course, occurs when using `git log -m -p` to *split* merge commits.  Normally `git log` skips merge commits entirely, while `git show` shows *combined diffs* for them.  (The documentation on combined diffs is somewhat buried—search here on StackOverflow for the term "combined diffs".)

If you convince `git log` to show a diff, it too can show a combined diff.  In all cases, combined diffs may omit crucial information, so you can tell these commands to do something different: for each parent of a merge, produce a diff of the merge commit's tree against that particular parent's tree.  This is what the `-m` flag does.

When showing a diff of commit merge commit `1234567...` against parent #1, Git shows you the merge commit information, then the diff.  Then, when showing a diff of merge commit `1234567...` against parent #2, Git shows you the merge commit information again, before the second diff.  So this is how `git log` can show the same commit more than once.

<sup>3</sup>You can also use `git -c user.name=whatever` and `git -c user.email=whatever`, or in this particular case, special Git environment variables.  Using `git -c` is especially convenient for one-off tests, as in [the answer I wrote recently about Git diff color options](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38778798/1256452).

Comment: Amazing answer! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

`git reflog` is another command.

Everytime the [***`HEAD`***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34519665/how-to-move-head-back-to-a-previous-location-detached-head/34519716#34519716) is changed, git store its old value in its `.git/log` folder and you can view it vi the git reflog command.

The meanning of the **"reflog identity"** is simply:

> Each commit will be grouped by author and title

Answer (score 0):

Note the `git reflog` identity/entry is about to change (2020, 4 years later)

With Git 2.29 (Q4 2020), Preliminary clean-up of the refs API in preparation for adding a new refs backend "`reftable`".

See [commit 523fa69](https://github.com/git/git/commit/523fa69c36744ae6779e38614cb9bfb2be552923) (10 Jul 2020) by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
See [commit de966e3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/de966e39a8ba585e6cb0483c49e562c2f6eb3f77), [commit ce57d85](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ce57d85645540fe59e8ec84929288361f1affae7) (10 Jul 2020), and [commit 9e35a6a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9e35a6a9865c3c9bc5b8908dcdd3a9a818612a6a) (30 Jun 2020) by [Han-Wen Nienhuys (`hanwen`)](https://github.com/hanwen).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 3161cc6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3161cc6e6bbfa3b2ac822b54006a1262448c1052), 30 Jul 2020)</sup>

> ### [`reflog`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/523fa69c36744ae6779e38614cb9bfb2be552923): cleanse messages in the `refs.c` layer
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Han-Wen Nienhuys</sup>

> Regarding reflog messages:
>
> - We expect that a reflog message consists of a single line.
>   The file format used by the files backend may add a `LF` after the message as a delimiter, and output by commands like "[`git log -g`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/523fa69c36744ae6779e38614cb9bfb2be552923/Documentation/rev-list-options.txt#L264)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt--g))</sup> may complete such an incomplete line by adding a `LF` at the end, but philosophically, the terminating `LF` is not a part of the message.
> - We however allow callers of refs API to supply a random sequence of `NUL` terminated bytes.
>   We cleanse caller-supplied message by squashing a run of whitespaces into a `SP`, and by trimming trailing whitespace, before storing the message.
>   This is how we tolerate, instead of erring out, a message with `LF` in it (be it at the end, in the middle, or both).
>
> Currently, the cleansing of the reflog message is done by the files backend, before the log is written out.
> This is sufficient with the current code, as that is the only backend that writes reflogs.
> But new backends can be added that write reflogs, and we'd want the resulting log message we would read out of "`log -g`" the same no matter what backend is used, and moving the code to do so to the generic layer is a way to do so.
>
> An added benefit is that the "cleansing" function could be updated later, independent from individual backends, to e.g. allow multi-line log messages if we wanted to, and when that happens, it would help a lot to ensure we covered all bases if the cleansing function (which would be updated) is called from the generic layer.
>
> Side note: I am not interested in supporting multi-line reflog messages right at the moment (nobody is asking for it), but I envision that instead of the "squash a run of whitespaces into a SP and rtrim" cleansing, we can `%urlencode` problematic bytes in the message *AND* append a `SP` at the end, when a new version of Git that supports multi-line and/or verbatim reflog messages writes a reflog record.
> The reading side can detect the presence of `SP` at the end (which should have been `rtrimmed` out if it were written by existing versions of Git) as a signal that decoding `%urlencode` recovers the original reflog message.

---

With Git 2.29 (Q4 2020), git reflog manages the `\t` for its entries.

See [commit 25429fe](https://github.com/git/git/commit/25429fed5ce134bce9f729d927ac397badae1959) (31 Jul 2020) by [Han-Wen Nienhuys (`hanwen`)](https://github.com/hanwen).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit dc3c6fb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/dc3c6fb56557bfa4a4f5ed5abca25f119ded6cde), 01 Aug 2020)</sup>

> ### [`refs`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/25429fed5ce134bce9f729d927ac397badae1959): move the logic to add `\t` to `reflog` to the files backend
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Han-Wen Nienhuys</sup>

> [523fa69c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/523fa69c36744ae6779e38614cb9bfb2be552923) ("`reflog`: cleanse messages in the [`refs.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/25429fed5ce134bce9f729d927ac397badae1959/refs.c) layer", 2020-07-10, Git v2.29.0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3161cc6e6bbfa3b2ac822b54006a1262448c1052)) centralized reflog normalizaton.
> **However, the normalizaton added a leading "`\t`" to the message**.
> This is an artifact of the reflog storage format in the files backend, so it should be added there.
>
> Routines that parse back the reflog (such as `grab_nth_branch_switch`) expect the "`\t`" to not be in the message, so without this fix, [`git reflog`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/25429fed5ce134bce9f729d927ac397badae1959/Documentation/git-reflog.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog))</sup> with `reftable` cannot process the "`@{-1}`" syntax.